# How to set timeout for TWISTED_SESSION cookie

Tags: python, twisted

When I run python Twisted server, there is a default cookie TWISTED_SESSION. However I don't know how to set cookie timeout for it. https://twistedmatrix.com does not provide any info about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Session.sessionTimeout](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.server.Session.html) attribute to control this.

```
from twisted.server.site import Session, Site

def longTimeoutSession(*args, **kwargs):
    session = Session(*args, **kwargs)
    session.sessionTimeout = 1234
    return session

site = Site(...)
site.sessionFactory = longTimeoutSession
```